# Optional field in schema interface

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have this user schema defined in a plone add-on to be used for multiple websites.

```
class IUser(Interface):
    userid = schema.TextLine(
        title=_("User id"),
        required=True,
        constraint=validate_userid,
    )

    email = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Email"),
        required=True,
        constraint=validate_email
    )

    optional_type = schema.Choice(
        title=_(u"User type"),
        vocabulary="user_types",
        required=True,
    )
```

Sometimes the `optional_type` field is needed sometimes not. `user_types` is saved in `portal_vocabularies`. I want the field to be used only when the vocabulary exists and I want it to be ignored when the definition is missing.

I mean, I want this field to work for websites where it is used, but the user schema also to work in other case. For the moment I receive this error: `ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass zope.schema.interfaces.IVocabularyFactory>, 'user_types').`

I know I can create an empty unused vocabulary, but do you have any better solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, but you can skip the error and make things look like the field doesn't exist. Good to know:

> in fact `user_types` is not the name of a vocabulary but the name of a vocabulary
>   factory ([source](https://community.plone.org/t/optional-field-in-schema-interface/7291))

So you can solve this without defining a vocabulary in portal_vocabularies. Just define a factory like:

**`foo.py`**:

```
from zope.interface import provider
from zope.schema.interfaces import IVocabularyFactory
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleTerm
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleVocabulary


@provider(IVocabularyFactory)
def user_types_vocabulary(context):
    items = [
        ('test1', u'Test value 1'),
        ('test2', u'Test value 2')
    ]

    terms = [
        SimpleTerm(value=pair[0], token=pair[0], title=pair[1])
        for pair in items
    ]
    return SimpleVocabulary(terms)
```

as utility:

**`configure.zcml`**:

```
  <utility name="user_types"
           component=".aaa.user_types_vocabulary" />
```

Then you can hide the field and just ignore it everywhere is not needed.